# Trying to clear a recyclerView and load with new objects

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am populating a recyclerView as follows:

```
  private void getAddressesFromDB() {

        AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... addressesIds) {
                Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "UID REGISTRADO ANTES DE CARGAR REECYCLER: " + user_id);
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://../direcciones_todas.php?id=" + user_id)
                        .build();
                try {
                    okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.d("HOLA ADDRESSES", "DIRECCION LEIDA: " + i);
                        Address address = new Address(object.getInt("id_address"), object.getString("address_image"),object.getString("cia"),
                                object.getString("fn"), object.getString("ln"),
                                object.getString("ad1"),object.getString("ad2"),object.getString("type"),
                                object.getString("city"),object.getString("state"),object.getString("zip"),
                                object.getString("phone"),object.getString("ext"),object.getInt("fromto"),
                                object.getString("user"));

                        addresses.add(address);
                    }


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
```

Sometimes, the recyclerView objects change at the remote server, and I need to reload the objects as needed.

I try to reload the objects from a button action:

```
  btn_refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              //  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                getAddressesFromDB();
            }
        });
```

The issue is that after clicking on the refresh button, the objects are shown again and repeated. I have tried several ways to clear the adapter or invalidating the recyclerView, but no success.

How could I clear the current objects and load the new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code above, you're simply adding more to the list. You are not really refreshing the list.

Clear the addresses first before adding to it. Do this before entering the loop.

```
...

JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string()); 

addresses.clear();

for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
...
```

Comment: Thank you, but I guess it is due to a cache issue. On the other hand, I need to clear addresses, not address.

Comment: If I execute the PHP file on the server, then the refresh button does its work, else, the objects seem to be reloaded, but not updated to the latest.

Comment: In that case, turn off the cache.:
Request.Builder builder = request.newBuilder().addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.
Update the AsynchTask third parameter to ArrayList and on postexecute method update the Arraylist data in the adapter class. In doInBackground method create a Arraylist of Address type and add all new address value to the arraylist;

```
  private void getAddressesFromDB() {

    AsyncTask<Integer, Void, ArrayList<Address>> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, ArrayList<Address>>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... addressesIds) {
            Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "UID REGISTRADO ANTES DE CARGAR REECYCLER: " + user_id);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://../direcciones_todas.php?id=" + user_id)
                    .build();
            try {
                okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());
ArrayList<Address> addressList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.d("HOLA ADDRESSES", "DIRECCION LEIDA: " + i);
                    Address address = new Address(object.getInt("id_address"), object.getString("address_image"),object.getString("cia"),
                            object.getString("fn"), object.getString("ln"),
                            object.getString("ad1"),object.getString("ad2"),object.getString("type"),
                            object.getString("city"),object.getString("state"),object.getString("zip"),
                            object.getString("phone"),object.getString("ext"),object.getInt("fromto"),
                            object.getString("user"));

                    addressList.add(address);
                }


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return addressList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Address> 
          addressDataList) {

            adapter.updateData(addressDataList);
        }
    };
```

And In adapter class create a public method updateData and update the previous list with new list.

```
   public void updateData(ArrayList<Address> addressListData){
   this.yourPriviousListReference = addressListData;
notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
address.clear(); // Clear the List first before adding new elements to avoid duplicates.
try {
     okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
 ....
 ....
 ....
 ....
     addresses.add(address);
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // call 'notifyDataSetChanged()' for the recycler view to repopulate the data
```

**UPDATE**
If you have issues clearing the previous data

1) Use the `ArrayList<~>()` as a local variable and reinitialize it everytime you fetch new data.

2) Create a new instance of the Adapter of your recyclerview and call `setAdapter();` again.